# GoogleMap URL in WebView Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview

I want to show the googleMap Url in Webview but its not loading.

My MapUrl is of type:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=4936185307050533391
```

Am using this webview code:

```
          webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        webview.loadUrl(Uri.parse(MapUrl).toString());
```

How to make it work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not a android pro at all but when i try the below code, it works.
**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</WebView>
```

**WebViewActivity.java**

```
    public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=4936185307050533391");
}
}
```